# Android: How to broadcast intent from native code?

Tags: android

Is it possible to broadcast an Intent from native code? If so, is there documentation and/or sample code pertaining to the relevant APIs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to call it by calling the Java API function - there is no JNI interface for intents.

First look up the class for `Intent`, then look up the methods for constructing intents and broadcasting them, and call them.

EDIT: Here is an *incomplete* example. `jniEnv` is passed into all your JNI functions.

```
jclass activityClass = jniEnv->FindClass("android/app/Activity");
jmethodID startAcitivtyMethod = jniEnv->GetMethodID(activityClass , "startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V");
jniEnv->CallVoidMethod(yourActivityObject, startAcitivityMethod, yourIntentObject);
```

Comment: very nice explanation. even if that was not complete description, you deserve +1.

Comment: but what if I want to call from a callback (in another thread), In which case I cannot get the jniEnv

Comment: Is there any solution like this for non-jni ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing complicated in broadcasting message from native code but only in case if the native function is called from Android Java application so you can pass a Context. As far as I know there is no such thing as Context for purely native applications therefore you can not broadcast an intent.

Answer (score 0):

Even a pure native application can broadcast an Intent.  That means, even when native activity is the launcher, we can still broadcast Intents.

Comment: Can you explain how? your answer contradicts the other answers here.