# Intents and onActivityResult in native/JNI

Tags: java, android, android-intent, java-native-interface

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080475/android-how-to-broadcast-intent-from-native-code) post one can see how to send an Intent from a native environment using JNI:

```
jclass activityClass = jniEnv->FindClass("android/app/Activity");
jmethodID startAcitivtyMethod = jniEnv->GetMethodID(activityClass , "startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V");
jniEnv->CallVoidMethod(yourActivityObject, startAcitivityMethod, yourIntentObject);
```

but is it possible and how can one use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() and onActivityResult() to get the result of startActivityForResult()?

How do you access the onActivityResult()?

Comment: How is this question related to Qt? Your jniEnv variable is an instance of a QtAndroidExtras class? Could you please clarify?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: It's just syntax difference on how to do the above 3 lines in Qt or as shown. I choose to show them without Qt syntax because I think more people are familiar with that.

Comment: Right, so this is not a Qt issue; removed the qt tag respectively.

Comment: Hey @Phataas were you able to figure this one out? I am trying to override `onActivityResult` from JNI as well.

Comment: @Noitidart I dont remember, but I do know Qt now support some kind activity/intent in the QtAndroidExtras module. Please let me know if you figure this out so we can update this post with an answer.

Comment: Thank you, will let you know :)

Comment: @Phataas I just got an idea. I used this technique on WinAPI. I spawned a brande new thread, this thread did not have a event loop running, so I created it there, and received events just to that thread. Could we maybe do something similar here? Create a new thread and give it a `onActivityResult`?

Comment: @Noitidart Did you check: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroid.html