# Dynamically create new thread and give it a onActivityResult

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

Instead of the override/hook into the current `onActivityResult` I am spawning a new thread. In this new thread I want to give it a `onActivityResult` listener, is this possible?

It is my attempt to work an alternative solution here - [Intents and onActivityResult in native/JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888182/intents-and-onactivityresult-in-native-jni?noredirect=1#comment58535835_20888182)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @DougStevenson I am trying to set up a listener to respond to me kicking off `startActivityForResult`. So I need to create a `onActivityResult` listener on runtime.

Comment: So in your Activity subclass you override `onActivityResult`... and then what needs to happen in a thread?  Why do you need a thread here?

Comment: THanks @DougStevenson for quick reply. The reason I needed a thread is because i do some heavy calculation, I like to do stuff off main thread. Now in this thread I am trying to set up a `onActivityResult` callback during run time.

Comment: What do you need to do with the result of your computation? And is there any reason why you wouldn't kick that off (into whatever threading mechanism) from within the activity's onActivityResult? You can't really "listen" for that callback, so this is probably what you have to do.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson again for the reply. Is there anyway to "create" that callback though? As a new thread does not have that set up no? I don't have access to `onActivityResult` I am actually doing this from JNI so I am only access on run time.

Comment: You can't listen to that event without bridging it yourself.  You would need to be able to implement or override that method in an activity and proxy it through JNI to your native code to deal with there.

Comment: Thanks very much @DougStevenson for that insight. I'll take that advice and dig that way :)

Answer (score 1):

`onActivityResult` is used by the Android system where you started an activity by the intent's `startActivityForResult`.  If you've started your own thread, what I would do is have your own listener, and then in the method `onActivityResult`, you can call your listener and the functionality in the other thread can know when it happens.

So:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

     public void startActivity(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
     }

     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         // call method in other thread
     }


}
```

If you're dealing with JNI, where you're calling a method in C, you can simply call the native method and it will be picked up in C

Comment: Thanks @Peter very much for your reply. I am kicking of the `startActivityForResult` without problems, but I need to create the `onActivityResult` listener. But how can I set this `onActivityResult` from runtime? I really appreciate your time.

Comment: In your other activity that was called, call `finish(1);` and that will end up calling your `onActivityResult()` in the parent activity

Comment: Thanks very much @Peter for the quick reply. However in my thread I haven't created/setup the onActivityResult yet. As I don't know how to create/setup `onActivityResult` callback on runtime, is this possible?

Comment: The Android system calls that method for you in your activity.  Basically, if, in your activity, you call `startActivityForResult`, and have implemented the method `onActivityResult`, when you call `finish()` in the sub-activity, `onActivityResult` should be called

Comment: Thanks again @Peter, however my issue is to implement this during runtime :(

Comment: I don't see a way to have the Android system call `onActivityResult` while you're in the JNI layer, BUT you can call a routine in the JNI layer, if your thread is running in C/C++ so that it can know.

Comment: Thanks very much I'll dig in this direction :)